# Maven project is not picking local repository after copying

Tags: maven-2

I had a working workspace set up in Maven. Due to unavoidable reasons I have to change my system and hence I need to set up a new workspace. Hence I copied the .m2/repository folder from a working system to the new system.

But unfortunately my local is nopt picking jars from the local repository and it is throwing compiler error. I have copied it to my home directory .m2/repository folder

Can anyone please help me here?

Thanks,
Rengasami R

Comment: What's the error? What do your `pom.xml` and `settings.xml` files look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local repository path is defined in your `settings.xml` file (found either in `M2_HOME/conf` or `USER_HOME/.m2`). Check that the value of this `<localRepository>` matches the path you have defined.

Another solution is to run the command `mvn help:effective-settings`, and it will display the content of the `settings.xml` Maven is using, so you will find this information easily.